# jQuery Find Previous Input val and copy

Tags: jquery

Trying to grab the value of a previous input value (input[placeholder="Days Paid"]) and populate the closest (input[placeholder="Days Paid"]) when clicking on the checkbox.

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thx :)

```js
jQuery('.days-paid-copy').click(function() {
  var copydays = jQuery(this).parent().prev('li').find('input[placeholder="Days Paid"]').val();
  jQuery(this).prev('input[placeholder="Days Paid"]').val(copydays);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li id="field_32">
  <div class="container">
    <input name="input_126" id="input_32_126" value="" placeholder="Days Paid" type="text">
  </div>
</li>

<li id="field_33">
  <div class="container">
    <input name="input_127" id="input_33_127" value="" type="text">
  </div>
</li>

<li id="field_34">
  <div class="container">
    <input name="input_128" id="input_34_128" value="" placeholder="Days Paid" type="text">
    <input class="days-paid-copy" name="" value="" type="checkbox">
  </div>
</li>

<li id="field_35">
  <div class="container">
    <input name="input_128" id="input_35_128" value="" type="text">
  </div>
</li>

<li id="field_36">
  <div class="container">
    <input name="input_129" id="input_36_129" value="" placeholder="Days Paid" type="text">
    <input class="days-paid-copy" name="" value="" type="checkbox">
  </div>
</li>
```

Comment: `$(this).parent()` is `<div class="container">`, not `<li>`, so there's no `.prev("<li>")`.

Comment: I don't understand where you're trying to get the value you're copying from. The previous LI doesn't have a `Days Paid` input, you have to go back 2 LIs for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not going up the DOM hierarchy enough before going to `.prev()`. `.parent()` is the `<div>`, not `<li>`.

Use `.closest("li")` to get to the containing list item.

And the previous `<li>` doesn't have a `Days Paid` input in it. If you want to find the nearest previous one, use `.prevAll()` to get all the previous LIs, find the `Days Paid` input in them, then get the last of those.

```js
jQuery('.days-paid-copy').click(function() {
  var copydays = jQuery(this).closest('li').prevAll('li').find('input[placeholder="Days Paid"]').last().val();
  jQuery(this).prev('input[placeholder="Days Paid"]').val(copydays);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li id="field_32">
  <div class="container">
    <input name="input_126" id="input_32_126" value="" placeholder="Days Paid" type="text">
  </div>
</li>

<li id="field_33">
  <div class="container">
    <input name="input_127" id="input_33_127" value="" type="text">
  </div>
</li>

<li id="field_34">
  <div class="container">
    <input name="input_128" id="input_34_128" value="" placeholder="Days Paid" type="text">
    <input class="days-paid-copy" name="" value="" type="checkbox">
  </div>
</li>

<li id="field_35">
  <div class="container">
    <input name="input_128" id="input_35_128" value="" type="text">
  </div>
</li>

<li id="field_36">
  <div class="container">
    <input name="input_129" id="input_36_129" value="" placeholder="Days Paid" type="text">
    <input class="days-paid-copy" name="" value="" type="checkbox">
  </div>
</li>
```